# Instagram API User Endpoint Error: Using parameter "max_like_id"

Tags: json, oauth, get, instagram-api, endpoint

I am developing an app using the Instagram API endpoints in sandbox mode. I am testing the following API calls using Postman.

So far, I am able to receive the authenticated user's likes by requesting the following url: 
    https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=TOKEN

As outlined in the the Instagram Developer Docs...(https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/)

...I should be able to get the latest likes by performing a GET to /users/self/media/liked and adding the MAX_LIKE_ID parameter.

The goal is to get the latest likes AFTER a certain like ID.

The problem occurs when I attempt to request the following url: 
    https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=TOKEN&max_like_id=MAX_ID

When I use a valid ID, the only response is: "Oops, an error occurred."

If I use a invalid ID, it simply ignores the parameter and displays the original like data returned by the first call to: 
    https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token=TOKEN

I have also tried to perform the request with other parameter variations in both lowercase and uppercase formats: MAX_ID, MIN_ID, etc.

Does anyone have any suggestions or has had a similar issue? Thanks for your help.

Comment: it will not work in sandbox mode, u can only get 20 posts in sandbox

Comment: There are only 3 or 4 total likes from the user, and I get those.  For example, if I set the max_like_id parameter to the 2nd Like object ID, it should only return the first two Like objects.  Alas, it just says "Oops".

Comment: I checked, it works in live mode, not in sandbox.